# Why test.modmed (mediation package - moderated mediation) does not find covariate?

Tags: r, interaction, causality, predictor, mediation

I am trying to do a moderated mediation analysis in R with the mediation package, test.modmed function.

In summary, my dataset consists in: Y = cell_size (continuous); X = body_size (continuous); Mediator = organ_size (continuous); Moderator = sex (factor: Female and Male).

I've followed the authors paper (link below) to build this model such as:

model_fitM <- lm(organ_size ~ body_size * sex, data=mydata)

model_fitY <- lm(cell_cise ~ body_size * sex + organ_size * sex, data=mydata)

model_MedMod <- mediate(model_fitM, model_fitY, treat="body_size", mediator="organ_size")

test.modmed(model_MedMod , covariates.1 = list(Sex = Female),
covariates.2 = list(Sex = Male))

This model does not recognize Sex = Male, regardless of being the covariate.1 or covariate.2.
The error is "Error in test.modmed.mediate(model_MedMod, covariates.1 = list(Sex = Female), : object 'Male' not found".

However, if I run a separate mediation model for each sex, it has no problem with it. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong with this model? Does anybody know why it doesn't find Sex = Male?

Thank you!

https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-02-04/web/packages/mediation/mediation.pdf

Comment: Did you try `list(Sex = "Male")`?

Comment: I did, but I get "Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels".
In the examples I've found online and in the original paper it always appears without "".

Comment: Also, it does recognise list(Sex = Females)

Comment: Actually, it only runs for each sex separately when I'm using two separate data sets, filtered per sex. If I'm running a model with covariates.1 = list(Sex = Female), covariates.2 = list(Sex = Male) or just covariates = list(Sex = Male) on the combined dataset, it doesn't find Male but it does Female.

I thought it could be related to the levels order, i.e, Female comes before so the estimates in summary(lm(...)) come with Female as reference. However, I've changed to "aMales" so that it's now the reference, but it's still not recognized in covariates = list(...) while Female is...

Comment: Fascinating. Sounds like a potential bug. Try recoding Sex as a numeric variable and re-running things.

Comment: Thank you Noah, coding it as numeric works! It must be some weird bug indeed...